# DELETE file invoking webscripts in Alfresco with Curl

Tags: curl, alfresco, http-delete

I'm new with Alfresco, Web Scripts and curl and I'm trying to delete a file in

```
Company home > Sites > mySite> documentLibrary > UploadedItems
```

The file is called `test.json`

I try to use the following Web Script:

```
DELETE /alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/action/file/site/{site}/{container}/{path}
```

Now, I invoke the web script like this:

```
curl -v -X DELETE  "http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/action/file/mySite/documentLibrary/UploadedItems/test.json"
```

When I do this, I get a 404 error.

Does anybody know how to invoke this webscript correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't normally be calling Slingshot APIs directly, they're not public and are for use by Share only. Is there a reason why you're not using something like CMIS to list/create/update/delete files instead?

Comment: See the [CMIS Web Script Reference](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Delete_Object_.28deleteObject.29) - the CMIS API provides `deleteObject` and `deleteTree` methods.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the slingshot APIs are not intended to be used directly. But to answer your question, it seems you are missing a part of the URL

You state the URL of the webscript is specified as

```
/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/action/file/site/{site}/{container}/{path}
```

but you have used

```
/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/action/file/{site}/{container}/{path}
```

You must add the `/site/` part of the path if you are using a path-based name. Otherwise the web script will not find your content item.

I've not seen the HTTP Basic username and password specified within the URL before (I normally use Curl's `--user` option), but if you're getting a 404 response then it may be that it's working for you.